# Crystal report with lot columns across pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I have report with 21 column and thousands rows.

Question is: Can I display 1-10 column on first page and 11-21 column on second page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can be done. There are some options you could try, like a cross-tab report, but usually when I run into this issue I simply set my report page up to display in landscape and then format it accordingly.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT:

SAP came through again. I knew if it could be done at all it needed to be with the use of a subreport. Please see this [post](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-47389) which has step-by-step instructions on how to achieve what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I already try that, but i still can't put all 21 column on page.

Comment: Well, you could try splitting your section, putting 1-10 in the first section, 11-21 in the second section, and in Section Expert you could check either the "New Page after" or "New Page Before" (can't remember which is available).

Comment: In that case, i first get all records for columns 1-10 and after that records for 11-21. And also have problems with page headers and sum.

Comment: This is good solution if you have few records (witch will fit on one page). If I use this solution i cant get page footer in sub report ( cant sum records on every page).